# How to utilize the batch function with multiple inputs to receive one agent from each input to meet the batch?

Tags: input, batch-processing, anylogic, agent

I have 8 inputs that I would like to combine to one agent using the batch block. All the inputs have the same flow rate (1 per minute) and I would like them all to deliver one and only one agent to the batch so all inputs deliver one agent for the batch to be complete.

I have tried to use a delay and queue to manually restrict flow but that has not worked. I got an error saying cannot restrict flow but I have the inputs set "agents that cant exist are destroyed".
I also looked into trying to use a function but have not come across one that makes sense in my problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is what the Assembler block is for. If you need 8 items, use 2 Assembler blocks with 4 inputs and a third combining them

Answer (score 0):

In a very primitive way you can build the following model:
[image]

You will define the HOLD block as follows:

[image]

The function will check that each queue has at least one agent ready and then release agents from each HOLD block:

```
if (queue.size() > 0 &&
    queue1.size() > 0 &&
    queue2.size() > 0 &&
    queue3.size() > 0 &&
    queue4.size() > 0 &&
    queue5.size() > 0 &&  
    queue6.size() > 0 &&
    queue7.size() > 0 )
{
   hold.unblock();
   hold1.unblock();
   hold2.unblock();
   hold3.unblock();
   hold4.unblock();
   hold5.unblock();
   hold6.unblock();
   hold7.unblock();
}
```

Every time an agent arrives you call the `function()` under the `onAtExit` event of your sources.